# ListContourPlot and ListContourPlot3D use better interpolation for arrays of values than for lists of tuples (i.e. {{x,y,z,f[x,y,z]}..}

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d

From reading the documentation, it seems that ListContourPlot3D should work equally well on an array versus a list of tuples,

```
?ListContourPlot3D
```

> ListContourPlot3D[array] generates a contour plot from a
> three-dimensional array of values.  ListContourPlot3D[{{$x_1$,$y_1$,$z_1$,$f_1$},{$x_2$,$y_2$,$z_2$,$f_2$},$\ldots$}]
> generates a contour plot from values defined at specified points in
> three-dimensional space.

But below, the plot on the left uses the tuples version, while the plot on the right uses the array,

```
dta = Table[{x, y, z, x^3 + y^2 - z^2}, {z, -2, 2, .1}, {y, -2, 
    2, .1}, {x, -2, 2, .1}];
Grid[{{ListContourPlot3D[Flatten[dta, 2], Contours -> {0}, 
    Mesh -> None],
   ListContourPlot3D[dta[[All, All, All, -1]], Contours -> {0}, 
    Mesh -> None, DataRange -> {#, #, #} &@{-2, 2}]}}]
```

[image]

The interpolation used for the array version is clearly superior.  Why is this?  [`InterpolationOrder`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolationOrder.html) is not an option for [`ListContourPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListContourPlot3D.html) (even an undocumented one).  Applying the option `MaxPlotPoints -> 120` produces this monstrosity

[image]

This problem seems to affect the output of [`ListContourPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListContourPlot.html) a little bit differently.  Without using `InterpolationOrder`, they give the same output (top row below), but if I do use `InterpolationOrder`, it only has an effect on the array, not the tuples.

```
dta = Table[{x, y, x^3 + y^2}, {y, -2, 2, .2}, {x, -2, 2, .2}];
Grid[{{ListContourPlot[Flatten[dta, 1], Contours -> 20],
   ListContourPlot[dta[[All, All, -1]], Contours -> 20]},
  {ListContourPlot[Flatten[dta, 1], Contours -> 20, 
    InterpolationOrder -> 3],
   ListContourPlot[dta[[All, All, -1]], Contours -> 20, 
    InterpolationOrder -> 3]}}]
```

[image]

Comment: According to the `ListContourPlot/3D` docs, there is a `Method` option which seems to deal with that problem ("the method to use for interpolation and data reduction") but no examples are available at all in the Options section ! I couldn't make it work, setting it with various def.

Comment: Interesting, looks like Szabolcs made [a post](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/204934) about that, but got no answer yet.  Also, anyone else find that Wolfram Community website has been insanely slow lately?  Unusable sometimes.

Comment: I think it has to do with interpolation, when you have a nice cuboidal array of numbers, interpolation between them is super easy and can be done easily for any order. When you have 'random' points in space then doing the interpolation is much harder (it doesn't recognize the numbers being in a 3D grid but treats them randomly), and can only be done up to order 1 (easily) I think.