# InterpolationOrder has no effect on ListContourPlot when the data is of the form {x,y,f[x,y]}

Tags: plotting, graphics, interpolation

This is related to the issue brought up [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/98145/listcontourplot-and-listcontourplot3d-use-better-interpolation-for-arrays-of-val), if you want to mark it as duplicate feel free to do so, but it is slightly separate.

Take two sets of data, identical except for the form,

```
dta1 = Table[Exp[-x^2] Sin[y], {y, -π, π, π/3}, {x, -8, 8, 1}];
dta2 = Table[{x, y, Exp[-x^2] Sin[y]}, {x, -8, 8, 1}, {y, -π, π, π/3}]~Flatten~1;
```

The first is a two-dimensional array and the second is a list of tuples.  Now note the different effects of `InterpolationOrder` on these data,

```
ListContourPlot[dta1, InterpolationOrder -> #, ImageSize -> 200, 
   DataRange -> {{-8, 8}, {-π, π}},PlotRange-> All] & /@ {0, 1, 2, 3}
```

[image]

```
ListContourPlot[dta2, InterpolationOrder -> #, 
   ImageSize -> 200,PlotRange -> All] & /@ {0, 1, 2, 3}
```

[image]

Going past an order of 1 has no effect.  At order zero they are identical, at order 1 the 2D array is already better.

Notice that this is not a problem for `ListLinePlot` with one-dimensional data

```
func = Exp[-#^2] Cos[4 #] &;
list1 = Table[func[x], {x, -5, 5, .5}];
list2 = Table[{x, func[x]}, {x, -5, 5, .5}];
ListLinePlot[list1, DataRange -> {-5, 5}, InterpolationOrder -> #, 
   PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, ImageSize -> 200] & /@ {0, 1, 2, 3}
ListLinePlot[list2, InterpolationOrder -> #, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, 
   ImageSize -> 200] & /@ {0, 1, 2, 3}
```

[image]

Comment: You forgot to hyperlink "here" in the first sentence.

Comment: D'oh!! I'm at home now so I'll have to do it in a bit. It was a post about interpolation in listcontouplot that I made recently

Comment: With Version 10.3, I was unable to reproduce these figures without `PlotRange -> All`.  Also, with `ListContourPlot` replaced by `ListPlot3D`, the addition of `Mesh -> All` produces what to me are surprising results.

Comment: I can't prove this, but I suspect that this is because in the first case you have an array of values that Mathematica can smoothly interpolate, but in the second case you are specifying a discrete domain at which the data are sampled, so interpolation order will never have an effect.  The option will not force the plot to try to upsample your data in this case.  The `DataRange` option in the first use of `ListContourPlot` is only telling Mathematica how you want the axes scaled.

Comment: @bbgodfrey -  sorry about that, forgot that I have `PlotRange->All` set in my `init.m` file.  In my opinion that should be the default, since the contour plots look atrocious without it.  That is also interesting how `Mesh->All` interacts with the `InterpolationOrder` option.

Comment: @djphd, it really ought to be able to upsample the data using the exact same interpolation routines that `Interpolation` uses.  Especially since the data provided by `dta2` is on a rectangular grid.