# Why Plot3D shows differently with almost the same data

Tags: plotting

I really can't understand this.

I wrote two functions, one with `Compile` called `funcom`, one with librarylink to link a fortran subroutine called `funcfortran`. And they do exactly the same thing! So I Plot the result first

```
plotfor=Plot3D[funcfortran[w, 0.06, -1, 1, 1, \[Pi]/2., 2., 3., ky], {w, 0, 
  10}, {ky, -0.1, 0.1}, PlotRange -> All, MaxRecursion -> 7, 
 Mesh -> All]
```

This is output from topview

[image]

Well, this may not seem that wrong, But look at the plot result of `funcom` with exactly the same parameter

```
plotcom=Plot3D[funcom[w, 0.06, -1, 1, 1, \[Pi]/2., 2., 3., ky], {w, 0, 
      10}, {ky, -0.1, 0.1}, PlotRange -> All, MaxRecursion -> 7, 
     Mesh -> All]
```

[image]

different !!!

They contains almost the same point data, this can be verified after we extract the data and compared the difference

```
Sort[DeleteDuplicates@
   Abs@Flatten[
     Cases[%58, x_GraphicsComplex :> x[[1]]][[1]] - 
      Cases[%66, x_GraphicsComplex :> x[[1]]][[1]]], Greater][[1 ;; 3]
 ]
```

The top three biggest differen

```
{8.00339*10^-8, 7.99922*10^-8, 7.99703*10^-8}
```

If I plot it on larger region, the plot of `funcfortran` is unacceptable, see following and corresponding Mesh->All version

```
Plot3D[funcfortran[w, 0.06, -1, 1, 1, \[Pi]/2, 2, 3., ky], {w, 0, 
  10}, {ky, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, PlotRange -> All, MaxRecursion -> 7]
```

[image][image]

and this is what `funcom` got

[image]

Again, the point data contained in these two plot is almost the same, `funcfortran` contains 8260 points and `funcom` contains 8264 points

On the other hand, I can "stupidly" calculation `funcfortran` on a regular rectangular mesh, and `ListPlot3D` get pretty nice result.

```
Block[{datatmp, klist, n1, n2},
  n1 = n2 = 100;
  klist = 
   Tuples[{Subdivide[-N@\[Pi], N@\[Pi], n1], 
     Subdivide[-N@\[Pi], N@\[Pi], n2]}];
  datatmp = 
   Flatten[Outer[
     funcfortran[#1, 0.005, -1., 1., 1., \[Pi]/2., 2., 3., #2] &, 
     Subdivide[0., 10., n1], Subdivide[-N@\[Pi], N@\[Pi], n2]], 1];
  data = Join[klist, Partition[datatmp, 1], 2]];

ListPlot3D[data, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

**So, strange things, it seems that `funcfortran` has no problem, because `ListPlot3D` gives good result. But why `Plot3D` fails?**

---

**update**

m_goldberg suggested that this maybe due to loss of precision of my fortran routine. But I want to demonstrate, How `Plot3D` is defective.

I choose a defective parameter region, and plot it

```
test = Plot3D[
  iterateG[w, 0.06, -1, 1, 1, \[Pi]/2, 2, 3., ky], {w, 2, 3}, {ky, 0, 
   0.5}, PlotRange -> All, MaxRecursion -> 7, Mesh -> None, 
  PlotPoints -> 50]
```

it outputs

[image]

To notice the two strange dark stripes.

Now we extract the data contained in `test` plot, and use `ListPlot3D`. As m_goldberg had pointed out, there is default interpolation, we can turn it off using `InterpolationOrder -> 1`

```
ListPlot3D[Cases[test, x_GraphicsComplex :> x[[1]]][[1]], 
 InterpolationOrder -> 1, Mesh -> None]
```

outputs

[image]

It is smooth!! And this time, same data, different behaviour between `Plot3D` and `ListPlot3D`!!

---

**update**

I attached a zip ([download here onedrive](http://1drv.ms/1WUlDOu)). Since librarylink is quite difficult to work with. So I have packed everything: .dll for win, .so for linux, source .f90, .nb etc. Hope everyone extract and open the .nb file should have no problem running it. Thank you for testing.

---

**Summary**

The bug hunting is over. The defective plot is due to my fortran code and off course my bad fortran coding. I wrote `cmplx` instead of `dcmplx` which cause the rounding of w parameter, loss of precision and finally the weird plot3d.

Many thanks for Jason B's kind help, I learned a lot of skill and insight for tracing such kind of bug. Also I recall that m_goldberg is the first one correctly pointed out that it must be due to loss of precision. I reget not pay enough attention to this. Finally thank all people who have concerned with this post and tried to help me.

Comment: It looks to me that your Fortran function is having loss of precision problems. I think you should analyze the numeric behavior of the two functions; it may enlighten you as to the source of your plotting difficulties. I don't think anyone reading your question can help much further without having access to your Fortran code and its running environment.

Comment: Further, I don't think the list plot casts any light on your issue. I suspect it interpolates your data and thus smooths it out nicely. Of course, if you like the look of the list plot, then that's the way for you to plot the Fortran function.

Comment: @m_goldberg Hi, m_goldberg, thank you for comment. But how to "analyze the numeric behavior of the two functions", I have no idea

Comment: @m_goldberg I updated my post, to show that interpolation is not the reason.

Comment: @matheorem - is there any way you can post the code for both `funcom` and `funcfortran`?  It looks like this has a couple of close votes, but I think this is a legitimate issue you are bringing up.  And for the record, rather than being "stupid", I think it is almost always better to generate a rectangular grid and plot based on some form of `ListPlot` than it is to use the corresponding `Plot`.  Basically, there are some decision making algorithms that decide which points to sample when making a `Plot` and you can circumvent those by sampling yourself.

Comment: @JasonB Thank you for interest in my post. I have add my code, see my update, hope you could have a look : ) And you are right, it is best to make a regular mesh first to get a whole view of the function. But adaptive plot has great advantage that it can treat sharp area with high fidelity, and the data that needs even lesser than regular mesh in terms of the same quaility

Comment: @m_goldberg Hi, m_goldberg. I have attached my code. See my update, hope you could see it. Thank you

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### Source of the problem (possibly)

Here is a clear indication that your Fortran library and the *Mathematica* function are behaving in fundamentally different ways.  I noticed the apparent high frequency oscillations in the difference functional, so I decided to see exactly how quickly they oscillate,

```
Plot[funcfortran[w, 0.06, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, N[π/2], 2.0, 3., 0.2] - 
    funcom[w + 0.06*I, π/2., 3., .2], {w, 2.75 - #, 2.75 + #}, 
   PlotPoints -> 800, 
   ImageSize -> 400] & /@ {.001, .0001, .00001, .000001}
```

[image]

So now we zoom in and plot them together on this scale,

```
Plot[{funcfortran[2.75 + dw, 0.06, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, N[π/2], 2.0, 
   3., 0.2],
  funcom[2.75 + dw + 0.06*I, π/2., 3., .2]},
 {dw, -.000001, .000001},
 PlotPoints -> 200,
 ImageSize -> 400,
 PlotLegends -> {"Fortran", "Mathematica"}]
```

[image]

So somewhere, Fortran is doing some kind of rounding.  Perhaps you have some number defined with single precision?  Probably not that simple or you would have caught it, but basically as you vary `w` in increments of the order $10^{-7}$ then the Fortran function does not vary smoothly.  This is not the case for the `ky` parameter.

I would next check whether you get this behavior from Fortran directly, without using `Mathematica`.  If so, the problem is in your code there.  If not, it must have to do with the library linking function.

As I try to show below, I think it is this nonlinear behavior in the Fortran function that leads *Mathematica* to plot it incorrectly when using the adaptive grid created by `ListPlot3D`.  I assume that `Plot3D` is trying to come up with derivatives to better plot, but at some points along the `w` axis the derivative is infinite.

You point out that `Plot` adaptively samples the plot region, so let's just extract the points that you get for both functions,

```
fortranlist = 
  Reap[Plot3D[
     Sow[{w, ky, funcfortran[w, 0.06, -1, 1, 1, π/2, 2, 3., ky]}];
      funcfortran[w, 0.06, -1, 1, 1, π/2, 2, 3., ky], {w, 0, 
      10}, {ky, -π, π}, PlotRange -> All, MaxRecursion -> 7, 
     PlotPoints -> 100]][[2, 1]];
funcomlist = 
  Reap[Plot3D[Sow[{w, ky, funcom[w + 0.06*I, π/2., 3., ky]}]; 
     funcom[w + 0.06*I, π/2., 3., ky], {w, 0, 
      10}, {ky, -π, π}, PlotRange -> All, MaxRecursion -> 7, 
     PlotPoints -> 100]][[2, 1]];
fortranlist[[2]]
fortranlist = Delete[evalcoords, 2];
```

That last line is necessary because the second element of `fortranlist` looks like this,

[image]

For those who want to weigh in, but don't want to evaluate the Fortran library function, you could just download the lists above via:

```
funcomlist=Import["https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/34581877899db27e1cf4/raw/409c85ce8d34cd8f90344cbd0291c08f29c68d9e/funcom_pts.dat","Table"];
fortranlist=Import["https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/1d377c32f675847839d6/raw/00f79e303e5ec787107082516bffe3148af8380e/fortran_pts.dat","Table"];
```

But we can now check that the adaptive grid for the two functions is identical,

```
funcomlist[[All, ;; 2]] == fortranlist[[All, ;; 2]]
(* True *)
```

And we can plot the two lists and their differences

```
ListPlot3D[#, ImageSize -> 450, PlotRange -> All] & /@ {funcomlist, 
  fortranlist, 
  Transpose[{funcomlist[[All, 1]], funcomlist[[All, 2]], 
    funcomlist[[All, 3]] - fortranlist[[All, 3]]}]}
```

[image]

And here is the density of grid points,

```
ListPlot[funcomlist[[All, ;; 2]]]
```

[image]

What I notice is that the regions where the differences between the function is largest is also the region with the highest density of grid points.  So in that region, *Mathematica* is trying to get many points so it can get a handle on the curvature in that region.  The Fortran function is not behaving well there, but this misbehavior is at a relatively small scale.  But the scale isn't **that** small.  The average value for the function is on the order of .1, and the differences are a factor of $10^{-6}$ smaller than that, but $10^{-6}$ is a good deal larger than machine precision.   So `Plot3D` is trying to get a handle on the higher order derivatives in that region, and isn't doing such a great job.

Why are there such large differences between the functions?  I'm not going to check through your Fortran code, but somewhere it has a difference.

So in this case, the adaptive sampling is working against you.  It is preferentially sampling a region where the precision of the Fortran function is less than optimal.  No amount of increasing `MaxRecursion` or `PlotPoints` will fix this, because they will just increase the sampling in that region.

Another point is that, at least in version 10, the interpolation algorithms for plotting functions like `ListContourPlot`, `ListPlot3D`, etc, do a **much** better job when given a rectangular grid than they do when given a list of tuples like `{x, y, f[x, y]}`.  See my question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/98145/listcontourplot-and-listcontourplot3d-use-better-interpolation-for-arrays-of-val).  And all `Plot3D` seems to do with the data it generates is to give it to `ListPlot3D`.  So you already know that you get a much better plot simply from creating a list and plotting it, but I would suggest not structuring that list in the form of tuples, but instead as a grid.

```
ListPlot3D[
 Table[funcfortran[w, 0.06, -1, 1, 1, π/2, 2, 3., 
   ky], {ky, -π, π, .05}, {w, 0, 10, .1}], 
 DataRange -> {{0, 10}, {-π, π}}]
```

It produces a better plot than `Plot3D`, and does it faster.  I'd be interested in hearing what @user21 thinks of this issue, I believe he works directly with the underlying functions here.

**Edit**

To your final point, I don't think that `Cases` is giving you every point that is plotted by `Plot3D`.  Consider this:

```
fortranlist2 = Reap[

    fortranplot = 
      Plot3D[Sow[{w, ky, 
         funcfortran[w, 0.06, -1, 1, 1, π/2, 2, 3., ky]}]; 
       funcfortran[w, 0.06, -1, 1, 1, π/2, 2, 3., ky], {w, 2, 
        3}, {ky, 0, 0.5}, PlotRange -> All, MaxRecursion -> 7, 
       Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 50];
    ][[2, 1]];
fortranlist2 = Delete[fortranlist2, 2];
fortranlist2b = Cases[fortranplot, x_GraphicsComplex :> x[[1]]][[1]];
```

`fortranlist2` was generated while plotting, using the `Reap` and `Sow` method, while `fortranlist2b` was generated using `Cases` off of the graphics object.  We can see that there is a lot more information in the first one,

```
Length /@ {fortranlist2, fortranlist2b}
(* {10337, 2584} *)
```

They both seem to conform to an almost rectangular grid, but clearly `Plot3D` corresponds to the data in the `Reap` and `Sow` method,

```
{fortranplot, ListPlot3D[fortranlist2, Mesh -> None], 
 ListPlot3D[fortranlist2b, Mesh -> None]}
```

[image]

If you evaluate the differences between the `Mathematica` and Fortran functions at the grid points defined above, then you see where your stripes come from

```
diff = {#1, #2, 
     funcfortran[#1, 0.06, -1, 1, 1, π/2, 2, 3., #2] - 
      funcom[#1 + 0.06*I, π/2., 3., #2]} & @@@ 
   fortranlist2[[All, ;; 2]];

ListPlot3D[diff]
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, finally someone gives an answer. Thank you Jason B for spending your time helping me. I am looking into your answer right now. Reap and Sow is showing something, but I think you maybe overlooked those dark stripes in the 3rd plot, they exactly corresponding those defective part of 2nd plot. But on these dark strips, there is no value difference, they are flat. I think this should be the key problem instead of those 10-6 differences, what do you think?

Comment: @matheorem I notice that the parameters you pass to `funcfortran` are not all reals (however they should) ... Just to be sure, does it make any difference ?

Comment: @SquareOne Sorry for the confusion. The parameter of `funcfortran` is all real,  while the w in `funcom` is complex. But it is just a sight difference in definition. I should had made it real also. But anyway, I just tried a modified real version of `funcom`, the result is the same

Comment: @matheorem I actually meant : is there a difference between calling `funcfortran[w, 0.06, -1, 1, 1, π/2, 2, 3., ky]` and `funcfortran[w, 0.06, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, π/2., 2., 3., ky]` where all the param. are reals ?

Comment: @SquareOne No difference : )

Comment: That is convincing finding. The two functions are so similar, I thought they should be the same, problem maybe due to plot3d. While it turn out that they are "drastically" different now. I have to recheck my fortran source.

Comment: Hope that helps, I think it's great fun to hunt down a bug

Comment: I really appreciate your help : )  I just checked my fortran source several time again, still finding nothing. I will check further, for they are actually not exactly the same, though I personally believe that should not matter that much. Now I am not quite sure whether it is a problem of my source or a problem of mixing C process, or a problem of librarlylink. So I am not that optimistic, maybe I need another person to shed some light on my fortran and C source too : )

Comment: But definitely a +1 first : )

Comment: What happens when you have the fortran code natively spit out a list over the values above?  is it in the stairstep pattern, or is it continuous?

Comment: That is a good idea, and I have confirmed my native fortran code already have this problem. What is more, even I remove the if branch in my code, it also produce the steps!! Damn! What on earth are they? Do you have any clever guesses? : )

Comment: Oh, I just notice you've already mentioned in your modified post. w is suspicious, let me check that

Comment: I got the bug!!! Just like you said, fortran is doing rounding there, it is due to `cmplx(w,wdelta)` in my fortran code, I should use `dcmplx(w,wdelta)`! Thank you Jason B. You are an excellent bug hunter! : )

Comment: @matheorem, glad to be of assistance

Comment: I thought as soon as a accept your answer, the 200 will automatically pass to you. I just know that it is not. Anyway, I just click on the bounty button, enjoy : )

Comment: Great!  So my turn for a silly question, but how do you turn a Fortran or c code into a mathematica-linked library?  I assume it starts with a piece of code that, when compiled, you call from the command line and pass a certain number of arguments of a certain type, but from there I don't know where to start.  Was there a guide you followed?

Comment: I am very glad I could show this to you : ) I packed the sample as a zip here http://1drv.ms/23MsJt5 The .nb file is written with instruction, hope I make myself clear, if you have any problem, drop me a comment. But I have to say, I haven't completely mastered this technique.

Comment: currently, I can only deal with intel compiler in windows and gcc in linux. I wish I could also done this with mingw in windows, in case of that I don't have a intel compiler. But I don't know how to include gfortran lib of mingw in win. I have asked a question, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/104668/problems-with-linking-fortran-with-librarylink?noredirect=1#comment284521_104668 the sad thing is, they close it!! They thought this is too specific. So I don't know if you can open the link or not?

Comment: And there is still mysteries in this topic. If you are interested in this, you have another interesting bug to catch : ) Have you read this http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/104382/4742 ? halirutan came up with very clever method to make any librarylink function Listable like Compile function. I successfully tested many librarylink, all works, except this one in the post. The problem is that if I make funcfortran listable, it will get different answers each evaluation.

Comment: The chat history is here http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/27047477#27047477  and I have found the "bug" line which is quite normal, I discussed it here http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/27356527#27356527