# Working Precision warnings for ParametricPlot

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions, machine-precision

I wish to plot a series of parametric curves for the following function called `poly` that has five parameters (`Γ`, `κ1`, `κ2`, `g1`, `g2`). My parameterization is such that `x = g1` and `y = g2` while the other three parameters eventually taking on constant values. I first have my equation:

```
27 (256 g1^6 + (4 g2^2 + (Γ - κ1) (Γ - κ2))^2 (4 g2 + κ1 - κ2) (4 g2 - κ1 + κ2) + 16 g1^4 (48 g2^2 - Γ^2 + 10 Γ κ1 - κ1^2 - 8 (Γ + κ1) κ2 + 8 κ2^2) + 8 g1^2 (96 g2^4 + 4 g2^2 (-10 Γ^2 + Γ κ1 - κ1^2 + 19 Γ κ2 + κ1 κ2 - 10 κ2^2) + (Γ - κ2) (-κ1 + κ2) (Γ^2 - 4 Γ κ1 + κ1^2 + 2 (Γ + κ1) κ2 - 2 κ2^2))) = 0
```

Which I then call all of the left hand side as `poly`:

```
poly = 27 (256 g1^6 + (4 g2^2 + (Γ - κ1) (Γ - κ2))^2 (4 g2 + κ1 - κ2) (4 g2 - κ1 + κ2) + 16 g1^4 (48 g2^2 - Γ^2 + 10 Γ κ1 - κ1^2 - 8 (Γ + κ1) κ2 + 8 κ2^2) + 8 g1^2 (96 g2^4 + 4 g2^2 (-10 Γ^2 + Γ κ1 - κ1^2 + 19 Γ κ2 + κ1 κ2 - 10 κ2^2) + (Γ - κ2) (-κ1 + κ2) (Γ^2 - 4 Γ κ1 + κ1^2 + 2 (Γ + κ1) κ2 - 2 κ2^2)))
```

Since I need my `g2` in terms of `g1` for my y-axis, I solve for `g2` in terms of all the other parameters (note that `g2` is a polynomial of order 6 so I should expect 6 solutions)

```
{g21p, g21n, g22p, g22n, g23p, g23n} = g2 /. (Solve[poly == 0, g2] /. {Γ -> 1/100, κ1 -> 2.0, κ2 ->3.25});
```

Where I have named each of the 6 solutions as `g21p`, `g21n`, `g22p`, `g22n`, `g23p`, `g23n` respectively and the parameters `Γ`, `κ1`, `κ2` all take on 0.01, 2, and 3.25 respectively. I now proceed to produce my parametric plot:

```
ParametricPlot[{{g1, g21p}, {g1, g21n}, {g1, g22p}, {g1, g22n}, {g1, g23p}, {g1, g23n}}, {g1, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> "Expressions", PlotPoints -> 100, Exclusions -> None]
```

And I am returned with:
[image]

Notice that there's a gap in between the curves. This could be slightly improved by setting `WorkingPrecision -> 10` (there is still a tiny gap in between)
[image]

However, I am returned with a bunch of warnings along the lines of `The precision argument function (one of the six g2 solutions) is less than WorkingPrecision (10.)` What is going on here and how can I remedy the warnings while fixing the gap?

Comment: One thing that helps is to use exact parameters in for `x1` and x2`.  (It fixes the problem with `WorkingPrecision`.)  Note that `MachinePrecision` is considered "less" than any arbitrary precision setting (see for instance [this commnet](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/182241/terrible-accuracy-of-dawsonf/182609#comment476939_182609)).

Comment: The gaps come from not hitting the exact points where the solutions become complex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using exact parameters and the correct endpoint

```
{g21p, g21n, g22p, g22n, g23p, g23n} = 
  g2 /. (Solve[poly == 0, g2] /. {Γ -> 1/100, κ1 -> 2, κ2 -> 325/100});

ParametricPlot[
 {{g1, g21p}, {g1, g21n}, {g1, g22p}, {g1, g22n}, {g1, g23p}, {g1, g23n}}, 
 {g1, 0, (523 Sqrt[523/3])/10800}, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> "Expressions", PlotPoints -> 100, 
 Exclusions -> None, WorkingPrecision -> 16]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks! This is very much what I needed. How did you know that the endpoint is at `(523 Sqrt[523/3])/10800`? That is an oddly specific number of around `0.6`. One would think that increasing the range up to a large amount (say `{g1, 0, 10}`) would include `0.6`. How did you figure out the endpoint?

Comment: @kowalski Solved for where the expression under the radical was zero.  Would've said something but I got interrupted while trying to figure why  [@halirutan's buttons](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1044/4999) got disabled by an upgrade to Safari.