NIntegrate cannot give high precision result for a well-behaved integral
I want to obtain value of following integral to a high precision (say 30 digits),
NIntegrate[DawsonF[Sqrt[t]]^2/t, {t, 0, Infinity}]

Graph of integrand looks like this: . There is no singularity whatsoever. When $t$ is large, integrand is of order $O(1/t^2)$, so the integral converge.

However, Mathematica seems unable to evaluate it to high precision. In version 14.1, it raises error when WorkingPrecision is over 30, even complains the integrand is not numeric.

Maple on other hand, can do this smoothly:


Is this a bug of NIntegrate? Any idea or suggestion is welcomed.

There might be some other options needed. But if you evaluate it exactly, then using N[exact,80] now it gives same result as Maple with no problems. https://i.sstatic.net/K6nIL7Gy.png  0.91596559417721901505460351493238411077414937428167213426649811962176301977625477

@Nasser Thank you for the comment. Actually my real problems are more complicated integrals involving DawsonF that Integrate cannot solve exactly (e.g. replace square by cube, 4th power etc). The above is a toy example to illustrate the problem I encountered when using NIntegrate on them.

Using @CarlWoll's answer to Terrible accuracy of DawsonF (which Q&A makes one suspect at least part of the problem is with DawsonF[]):
(*https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/182691*)
dawsonF[x_] := -(I/2) E^-x^2 Sqrt[\[Pi]] + I HermiteH[-1, I x]

NIntegrate[dawsonF[Sqrt[t]]^2/t, {t, 0, Infinity}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 160, MaxRecursion -> 20] // N[#, 80] &
(*
0.91596559417721901505460351493238411077414937428167213426649811962176301977625477
*)


Addendum
I had said, "at least part of the problem...", because there was some strange behavior I encountered in exploring the problem. I didn't have time to track it down.  But thanks in part to @BobHanlon's observation, I now know a little more and have reported the (mis)behavior to WRI support ([Case: 5208413]).
The problem is that in conditions I do not fully understand, the integrand evaluates to Indeterminate. I think NIntegrate[] tries to work around these points, perhaps as if they were removable singularities.  However, when that happens, either the accuracy is greatly diminished, or NIntegrate[] fails with a NIntegrate::inumri error ("evaluated to...Indeterminate...") and returns the input.
Consider a call of the following form:
NIntegrate[DawsonF[Sqrt[t]]^2/t, {t, 0, Infinity},
 MinRecursion -> min, MaxRecursion -> max, WorkingPrecision -> wp]

If min == max, then NIntegrate[] will run pretty well: No Indeterminate values will be generated and the error will be as low as possible for that level of recursion. You may get a NIntegrate::ncvb ("failed to converge") message if the error is too high for the precision goal at the given WorkingPrecision.
If min is a high enough recursion level to meet the precision goal, then increasing max has no effect.
If min is not a high enough recursion level, then increasing max is expected to lower the error. This is what happens until Indeterminate values of the integrand are generated. This seems to happen when the error dips below 10^-wp or so.  The error jumps up to around 10^-9 and seems to increase slightly as max increases, the opposite of what one expects. Eventually, NIntegrate[] fails with a NIntegrate::inumri error as mentioned above.
So the "trick" to using the built-in DawsonF[] in the OP's problem is to guess the right MinRecursion/MaxRecursion level for the desired WorkingPrecision.
Strangely enough, if the integrand is evaluated at the values of t that generated Indeterminate in an NIntegrate[] call, the value is computed correctly. It does not return Indeterminate. That is why I suspect that NIntegrate[] shares the blame.
Code for exploration:
count = 0;(* set less than 6 to Echo Indeterminate values *)
obj[t_?NumericQ] := Block[{res},
   res = DawsonF[Sqrt[t]]^2/t;
   If[! NumberQ[res],
    If[ListQ[foo],
     foo = {foo, Hold[DawsonF[Sqrt[t]]^2/t] -> res},
     foo = {Hold[DawsonF[Sqrt[t]]^2/t] -> res}
     ];
    If[++count <= 6, Echo[t -> res]]
    ];
   res
   ];
foo = {};(* reset to empty list before NIntegrate[obj[t]...] *)
NIntegrate[obj[t], {t, 0, Infinity}, MinRecursion -> 3, 
 MaxRecursion -> 5, WorkingPrecision -> 80]
foo // Flatten // Length (* number of Indeterminate values *)


$Version

(* "14.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

For comparison,
int = Integrate[DawsonF[Sqrt[t]]^2/t, {t, 0, Infinity}]

(* Catalan *)

intN = NIntegrate[DawsonF[Sqrt[t]]^2/t, {t, 0, Infinity},
  WorkingPrecision -> 30,
  MaxRecursion -> 25,
  MinRecursion -> 25]

(* 0.915965594177219015054603514932 *)

int - intN

(* 0.*10^-31 *)


Nice. MinRecursion -> 4 seems the min needed. NIntegrate[DawsonF[Sqrt[t]]^2/t, {t, 0, Infinity}, WorkingPrecision -> 80, MinRecursion -> 4] is accurate to 80 digits. Not sure why it is needed.
