# Make your own ListSliceContourPlot3D

Tags: plotting, interpolation, visualization

I have a fairly complicated scalar analytical function of 3 variables that appears to be quite incompatible with `SliceContourPlot3D` (I shut it down after a few minutes without results). What is the correct way to visualize it in 3D space using not 3D data array as suggested by `ListSliceContourPlot3D`, but rather precalculated data on 2D planes which I'm trying to visualize? In other words, I'm trying to do `ListContourPlot` in few different planes and arrange results in 3D space accordingly.

Also there is another problem when `ListContourPlot3D` gives empty box:
A [dump file](http://drive.google.com/file/d/1PyfmwQ1fGJgnQP3Xkko-8tyqTiD_z1oE) with NNSolution array that creates empty `ListSliceContourPlot3D[NNSolution, "CenterPlanes"]`.

Example:

Structured tables look alright:

```
data = Table[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2], {z, 0, 3, 0.1}, {y, 0, 3, 0.1}, {x, 0, 3, 0.1}];
ListSliceContourPlot3D[data, "CentralPlanes"]
```

[image]

But unstructured data is pretty bad:

```
data1 = Flatten[
          Table[
            {x, y, z, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2]}, 
            {z, 0, 3, 0.1}, {y, 0, 3, 0.1}, {x, 0, 3, 0.1}
          ],
        1];
ListSliceContourPlot3D[data1, "CentralPlanes"]
```

[image]

In two-dimensional case they are indistinguishable:

```
data1 = Flatten[Table[{z, y, Sqrt[y^2 + z^2]}, {z, 0, 3, 0.1}, {y, 0, 3, 0.1}], 1];
ListContourPlot[data1]
```

[image]

```
data = Table[Sqrt[y^2 + z^2], {z, 0, 3, 0.1}, {y, 0, 3, 0.1}];
ListContourPlot[data]
```

[image]

This is a rationale for using 2D contours and aligning them in 3D instead of 3D slice plot.

This is my silly version:

```
data1 = Flatten[Table[{x, y, Sqrt[(y + 1/2)^2 + (x - 1/2)^2]}, {x, -2, 2, 0.1}, {y, -2, 2, 0.1}], 1];
data2 = Flatten[Table[{y, z, Sqrt[(0 - 1/2)^2 + (y + 1/2)^2 + z^2]}, {y, -2, 2, 0.1}, {z, -2, 2, 0.1}], 1];
data3 = Flatten[Table[{x, z, Sqrt[(x - 1/2)^2 + (0 - 1/2)^2 + z^2]}, {x, -2, 2, 0.1}, {z, -2, 2, 0.1}], 1];
aa1 = Image[
ListContourPlot[data1, Frame -> False, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Contours -> {0.15, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5}], ImageSize -> 200];
aa2 = Image[ListContourPlot[data2, Frame -> False, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Contours -> {0.15, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5}], ImageSize -> 200];
aa3 = Image[ListContourPlot[data3, Frame -> False, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Contours -> {0.15, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5}], ImageSize -> 200];
ParametricPlot3D[{{x, y, 0}, {0, x, y}, {x, 0, y}}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
PlotStyle -> {Texture[aa1], Texture[aa2], Texture[aa3]}, Mesh -> False]
```

[image]

Note that textures look blurry and the whole thing is quite slow.

Comment: Instead of just assuming `ListSliceContourPlot3D` is broken, please post your attempt - most likely it can be fixed without having to reimplement a built-in function

Comment: @Mathe172 you can fix the fact that creating a 3D array requires much more computations than a few 2D arrays. ListContour plots look bad even in 2D when number of points is low, not to mention 3D.

Comment: Sorry, misread the question slightly - but showing some code still wouldn't hurt, normally that significantly increases the chance of getting answers

Comment: Also, did you look at the second form of `ListSliceContourPlot3D`? It essentially accepts sparse data...

Comment: @Mathe172 I added some examples.

Comment: Perhaps related: [ListContourPlot and ListContourPlot3D use better interpolation for arrays of values than for lists of tuples](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/98145/27951).

Comment: @MarcoB but what do I do when the region is not square so array does not exist?

Comment: @VsevolodA. Going back to the start of this discussion, *please* post your actual function, and the code you used for `SliceContourPlot`. The fact that it didn't immediately work out of the box may not necessarily mean that it's impossible to make it work. Without specifics of your actual case, we cannot do much more than guess.

Comment: @MarcoB considering that even toy example doesn't work properly I doubt describing the function will be of any significance. I added a simple realization though.

Comment: Why not `Flatten` to level 2 rather than level 1: that is, `data2 = Flatten[Table[{x, y, z, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2]}, {z, -2, 2, .1}, {y, -2, 2, .1}, {x, -2, 2, .1}], 2]; ListSliceContourPlot3D[data2, "CenterPlanes"]`?

Comment: @kglr oh wow. Maybe you got an idea why I'm getting empty output for my data? https://pastebin.com/Pp02hcUk

Comment: @kglr no wait if I copy it from pastebin it works.

Comment: @kglr here is a dump file with NNSolution array that creates empty `ListSliceContourPlot3D[NNSolution, "CenterPlanes"]` https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PyfmwQ1fGJgnQP3Xkko-8tyqTiD_z1oE My version is 11.2

Comment: @VsevolodA., cannot open the file you shared. Maybe you can add it in your post?

Comment: @kglr can you download it?

Answer (score 3):

The data in your example is actually structured. If you change the level specification in `Flatten` to `2` the result is the same as the one you get using your `data`:

```
data2 = Flatten[Table[{x, y, z, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2]}, {z, -2, 2, .1}, 
  {y, -2,  2, .1}, {x, -2, 2, .1}],  2]; 
ListSliceContourPlot3D[data2, "CenterPlanes"]
```

[image]

**Update:** An alternative way to use 2D `ContourPlots` as center planes:

```
ClearAll[postprocess]
postprocess = MapIndexed[(# /. Graphics[ GraphicsComplex[c_, prims___], ___] :> 
  Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[Function[{t}, Insert[t, 0, #2[[1]]]] /@ c, 
   {Opacity[0.8], prims}]]) &, #]&;

data0 = Flatten[Table[{x, y, z, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2]}, {z, -2, 2, .1}, 
  {y, -2, 2, .1}, {x, -2, 2, .1}], 2];
data2D = data0[[All, {## & @@ #, 4}]] & /@ Subsets[Range[3], {2}];
lcp2D = ListContourPlot[#, Contours -> 10, PlotRange -> All, 
     ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", ContourStyle -> Thick] & /@ data2D;
Show[postprocess @ lcp2D, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Your implementation is much better, thank you. However there's something wrong - if I change `x` to `x-1` in function from data0, it tears, like one of the planes is not showing what it should.